# forEach on array not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, internet-explorer-11

Hi I get this error in the console: "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'" in ie11 but as far as I know it's not supported on nodelist but I'm adding them into an array. Using babel as well.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".primary li a")).forEach((element,index) 
=> {
    element.classList = "";
});
```

I have lots of them in my code maybe I can add support for ie somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uhh, `forEach`works fine in IE11, but `Array.from` and arrow functions are not supported in IE11.

Comment: According to mdn `Array.from` is not supported in ie11 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: ^^ and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ...

Comment: using babel shouldn't that compile ?

Comment: using babel would work

Comment: it does not convert array.from, ended up using polyfill

Answer (score 3):

you should use below library to support es6 syntax in IE

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 3):

Use this code for converting NodeList to Array in IE 11

```js
var div_list = document.querySelectorAll('div'); // returns NodeList
var div_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(div_list); // преобразует NodeList в Array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Array.from [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill#Polyfill):

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 6, 22.1.2.1
if (!Array.from) {
  Array.from = (function () {
    var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
    var isCallable = function (fn) {
      return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
    };
    var toInteger = function (value) {
      var number = Number(value);
      if (isNaN(number)) { return 0; }
      if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) { return number; }
      return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
    };
    var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
    var toLength = function (value) {
      var len = toInteger(value);
      return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
    };

    // The length property of the from method is 1.
    return function from(arrayLike/*, mapFn, thisArg */) {
      // 1. Let C be the this value.
      var C = this;

      // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLike).
      var items = Object(arrayLike);

      // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
      if (arrayLike == null) {
        throw new TypeError('Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined');
      }

      // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
      var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
      var T;
      if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
        // 5. else
        // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
        if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
          throw new TypeError('Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function');
        }

        // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
        if (arguments.length > 2) {
          T = arguments[2];
        }
      }

      // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
      // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
      var len = toLength(items.length);

      // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
      // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method 
      // of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
      // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
      var A = isCallable(C) ? Object(new C(len)) : new Array(len);

      // 16. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;
      // 17. Repeat, while k < len… (also steps a - h)
      var kValue;
      while (k < len) {
        kValue = items[k];
        if (mapFn) {
          A[k] = typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T, kValue, k);
        } else {
          A[k] = kValue;
        }
        k += 1;
      }
      // 18. Let putStatus be Put(A, "length", len, true).
      A.length = len;
      // 20. Return A.
      return A;
    };
  }());
}
```